# Is there anyway to insert data to table with 2 different foreign keys from 2 different tables?

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets, prepared-statement

I have trouble when inserting data from jsp to database. I have 3 tables:

Books(bookid), Users(id), Review(b_id,u_id) , foreign key b_id, u_id references to 2 table above. Here is my code so far:

java

```
public void insert(ReviewModel model) {
    try {
        String b_id = null;
        String u_id = null;
        String sql = "insert into review (content,datePost,rating,b_id,u_id)\n"
                + "values (?,?,?,(select BookID from Books where BookID = '" + b_id + "'),(select id from Users where id  = '" + u_id + "') )";
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(sql);
        statement.setString(1, model.getContent());
        statement.setDate(2, (Date) (model.getDatePost()));
        statement.setFloat(3, model.getRating());
        statement.setInt(4, model.getBookid());
        statement.setInt(5, model.getUserid());
        statement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReviewDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using transactions?  Get a connection, set auto commit to false, do multiple inserts, call commit().  Also use try-with-resources when opening database connections, preparing statements or getting result sets (look it up), so avoid db resource leaks.

Comment: You only have 3 question marks in your query. but you're passing 5 parameters. Next time, instead of saying "I have trouble", post the exact and complete stack trace of the exceptions. Error messages are supposed to be read, not ignored. They tell you what and where the problem is, so that you don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
"...where BookID = '" + b_id + "')..."

statement.setInt(4, model.getBookid());
statement.setInt(5, model.getUserid());
```

The number of set parameters and the question marks must match.
You try to bind it as a named parameter, however in your sql you just concat a null string to it. 
So either remove the parameter setter lines above and fill up the string variables like

```
String b_id=mode.getBookId()
```

or use placeholder of '?' :  `... where BookID = ? ...`

(use the latter one, the first one is vulnerable to sql injection)